# C# selenium how to open a new tab on any page

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, tabs, action

I need to reliably open a new tab when using selenium.

Using an action doesn't work

```
Actions a = new Actions(driver);

a.KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.LeftControl);
a.SendKeys("t");
a.KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.LeftControl);

a.Perform();
```

Using javascript fails if the site has popups blocked

```
(driver as IJavaScriptExecutor).ExecuteScript("window.open()");
```

Using the command prompt fails if the browser is using marionette or not the default browser

```
Process.start("https://google.com/");
```

How can I reliably open a new tab using selenium?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open a blank page in the tab, you could do

```
driver.ExecuteScript("window.open('about:blank','_blank');");
```

in case, you wanna load up with some website

```
driver.ExecuteScript("window.open('your URL', '_blank');");
```

should work for you.

Comment: It does not work if the window is on a url that has popups blocked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, according to W3C standard, there is an endpoint to do the operation you're looking for:
https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#dfn-new-window

It's already implemented in the case of ChromeDriver:
https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/docs/chromedriver_status.md

All you have to do is to retrieve the HTTP executor from the WebDriver and call the endpoint directly (ChromeDriver is just an HTTP server after all)